# ANDROID When I uninstall my app and I install again the directory folders are different

Tags: android, android-sqlite, apk

I am developing app that have a database pre-ready in asset folder and when I install the app the database are sent to databases folder. Everything works when it´s first time I install or  when I delete the folders directly, but when I uninstall and install again the app my databases folder that should are empty already have a database.

**My app folder when it´s first time:**

[image]

**My app folder when it´s second time:**

[image]

because of that my app crash, because the database that is inside databases folder is empty.

I need to find a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved resolve it by setting these two manifest attributes to "false":

```
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupContent="false"
```